# Maple: solve with a variable or fsolve without variable return different result

Tags: maple

I've encountered a very strange issue with Maple. Hopefully to get an answer from here.

The result returns differently with solve and fsolve after/before a variable is given a certain value. [See attachment](http://www.mapleprimes.com/view.aspx?sf=221436_question/Maple_Question_Solve_Fsolve.mw) and/or [PDF exported from Maple](http://www.mapleprimes.com/view.aspx?sf=221436_question/Maple_Question_Solve_Fsolve.pdf)

The result comes from solve (with variable epsilon) returns value of the same variable with imaginary part while the fsolve returns the correct answer.

Now how can I achieve the same result as fsolve via solve?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because of the way you use `assign`. The output of your `solve` step is multiple lists on the form

```
{x = 1, y = 2},{x = 2, z = 3}
```

If you try to run `assign(%)` then only the last list will be used. That means `x = 2`, `z = 3` and `y` will be *unassigned*.

Instead, get the values of $d_0$ by a sequence call, taking the first element of each list and print it. We have used `allvalues` because [`solve` was returning expressions involving RootOfs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42188520/3560695).

```
sol := solve({eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6}, {d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3]}) assuming epsilon::real:
epsilon := -.1
allvals := allvalues(sol);                     ## Gives all the solutions. 
seq(allvals[i][1],i = 1..numelems([allvals])):
print~([%])[];
```

> ```
> d[0] = 9.849912475 - 1.375424440 I
> d[0] = 9.600120375
> d[0] = 14.45330059
> d[0] = 9.849912475 + 1.375424440 I
> ```

Alternatively, you can set `epsilon` before the `solve` step to avoid the `allvalues` part.

Note that the `fsolve` only captures one of the analytic solutions as expected.

Comment: Bravo! You nailed it! :)